# bootstrap-datepicker-rails - select date will not persist

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, coffeescript, bootstrap-sass

I've installed the following gems and am trying to implement a datepicker. The datepicker shows up in the field but when I select a date, the data does not persist or even show up in the field. Am I making a mistake with my coffeescript or html - or is this possibly an incompatibility between the gems?

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

[http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)

https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

articles.js.coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  $('#datepicker').datepicker()
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    weekStart: 0
    autoclose: true
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field" id="datepicker" data-date="current" > 
  <%= f.label :due %>
  <%= f.text_field :due, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap date picker format you need format the date this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-behaviour=datepicker]').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the raw files from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ and place them into your javascripts and stylesheets directories respectively.  Then, in your application.js make sure you have

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

In you application.css files

```
*= require datepicker
```

In your view file, first try this simple line of code (you can have it inside a div, but delete the id in your div):

```
<%= f.text_field :due, :id => "datepicker" %>
```

and (at the end of the same file)

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'});
</script>
```

Comment: Did this answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

The date picker you have used must be conflicting with some other javascript. try using it on the same page as where you have placed the date picker.

Comment: Please move this into the comment section of the question since it isn't a solution to the problem per say.